# Android - JNI crash in call to CallVoidMethodV

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have JNI native code that calls C++ and it starts background threads. In one of those threads, JNI is called but it ends with error:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: mid == null in call to CallVoidMethodV
Runtime aborting...
```

The code crashes on call:

```
lockedEnv->CallVoidMethod(cachedCaller,
                javaCallback,
                snapshotData);
```

Interesting is that the problem (crash) orrurs in the Release build of C++ with optimizations while debug mode works correctly.
Also, I am using the JNIClass wrapper on other places and no problems occur.

My JNI method is:

```
JNIClass * snapshotDataClass;

#define RETURN(type) JNIEXPORT type JNICALL
#define PACKAGE(fn) Java_com_example_NativeAPI__##fn

jbyteArray convertToJavaByteArray(JNIEnv *env, const jbyte *array, int elementCount) {
    if (elementCount == 0){
        return env->NewByteArray(1);
    }
    if (array == nullptr){
        return env->NewByteArray(elementCount);
    }

    jbyteArray res = env->NewByteArray(elementCount);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(res, 0, elementCount, array);

    return res;
}


RETURN(void) PACKAGE(getData)(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject caller) {

    if (dataClass == nullptr) {
        dataClass = new JNIClass(env, "com/example/Data");
        dataClass ->AddMethod("<init>", "()V");        
        dataClass ->AddMethod("setData", "([B)V");
    }


    jclass callbackClass = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("com/example/Data/DataListener"));
    jobject cachedCaller = (jobject) env->NewGlobalRef(caller);
    jmethodID javaCallback = env->GetMethodID(callbackClass, "onSnapshotRetrieved", "(Lcom/example/Data;)V");

       CppGetData([=](Result res) {
        //this is called from thread
        JNIEnv *lockedEnv = dataClass->LockEnv();

        dataClass->InitNewInstance();
        dataClass->RunVoid("setData", convertToJavaByteArray(lockedEnv, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte *>(res.data),  res.size));
           
        lockedEnv->CallVoidMethod(cachedCaller,
            javaCallback,
            dataClass->instanceRef);

        lockedEnv->DeleteGlobalRef(callbackClass);
        lockedEnv->DeleteGlobalRef(cachedCaller);

        dataClass->UnLockEnv();
    });
}
```

And JNI class is a helper wrapper:

```
struct SimpleJNIClass {
    JavaVM* vm = nullptr;
    jobject instanceRef = nullptr;
    JNIEnv *lockedEnv = nullptr;

    SimpleJNIClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject instanceRef){       
        env->GetJavaVM(&this->vm);
        this->instanceRef = (jobject)env->NewGlobalRef(instanceRef);
    };

    SimpleJNIClass(JNIEnv * env){
        env->GetJavaVM(&this->vm);
    };

    SimpleJNIClass(const SimpleJNIClass & ) = delete;

    virtual ~SimpleJNIClass() {
        if (this->vm == nullptr) {
            return;
        }

        if (JNIEnv * env = GetEnv()){
            env->DeleteGlobalRef(this->instanceRef);
            this->instanceRef = nullptr;
            FreeEnv(env);
        }
    };


    JNIEnv * LockEnv() {
        this->envMutex.lock();
        this->lockedEnv = this->GetEnv();
        return this->lockedEnv;
    };

    void UnLockEnv() {
        this->lockedEnv = nullptr;
        this->FreeEnv(this->lockedEnv);
        this->envMutex.unlock();
    };


protected:
    bool attachCurrentThread = false;
    std::recursive_mutex envMutex;

    JNIEnv * GetEnv(){
        if (this->lockedEnv != nullptr){
            return this->lockedEnv;
        }

        JNIEnv * env = nullptr;
        int getEnvStat = vm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);

        if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED){
            if (vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) != 0){
                MY_LOG_ERROR("AttachCurrentThread was not successful. "
                                     "This may be due to the thread being attached already to another JVM instance.");
            }
            else{
                attachCurrentThread = true;
            }
        }
        else if (getEnvStat == JNI_OK){
            //no need to attach, already attached
        }
        else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION){
            MY_LOG_ERROR("GetEnv: version not supported");
        }

        return env;
    };

    void FreeEnv(JNIEnv * env){
        if (this->lockedEnv != nullptr){
            return;
        }
        if (attachCurrentThread){
            vm->DetachCurrentThread();
            attachCurrentThread = false;
        }
    };
};


struct JNICallback : public SimpleJNIClass {    
    jmethodID callbackMethod = nullptr;

    JNICallback(JNIEnv *env, jobject classRef,
        const std::string & methodName, const std::string & methodSignature)
        : SimpleJNIClass(env, classRef){
        jclass callbackClass = (jclass)env->GetObjectClass(this->instanceRef);
        this->callbackMethod = env->GetMethodID(callbackClass, methodName.c_str(), methodSignature.c_str());
    };

    JNICallback(const SimpleJNIClass & ) = delete;

    virtual ~JNICallback() {
        callbackMethod = nullptr;
    };

};


struct JNIClass : public SimpleJNIClass {    
    jclass callbackClass;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, jmethodID> callbacks;    

    JNIClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject classRef)
        : SimpleJNIClass(env, classRef){
        this->callbackClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef((jclass)env->GetObjectClass(this->instanceRef));
    };

    JNIClass(JNIEnv *env, const std::string & classRefName)
        : SimpleJNIClass(env){
        this->callbackClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass(classRefName.c_str()));
    };

    virtual ~JNIClass() {
        if (JNIEnv * env = this->GetEnv()){
            env->DeleteGlobalRef(callbackClass);
            callbackClass = nullptr;
            this->FreeEnv(env);
        }

        callbacks.clear();
    };



    void AddMethod(const std::string & methodName, const std::string & methodSignature) {
        if (this->lockedEnv != nullptr){
            this->callbacks[methodName] = this->lockedEnv->GetMethodID(this->callbackClass, methodName.c_str(), methodSignature.c_str());
            return;
        }

        JNIEnv *env = this->LockEnv();
        this->callbacks[methodName] = env->GetMethodID(this->callbackClass, methodName.c_str(), methodSignature.c_str());
        this->UnLockEnv();
    };


    template<typename... Args>
    void InitNewInstance(Args... args){
        if (this->lockedEnv != nullptr){
            jobject inst = this->lockedEnv->NewObject(this->callbackClass, this->callbacks["<init>"], args...);
            this->SetInstance(inst);
            return;
        }

        JNIEnv *env = this->LockEnv();
        jobject inst = env->NewObject(this->callbackClass, this->callbacks["<init>"], args...);
        this->SetInstance(inst);
        this->UnLockEnv();
    };

    template<typename... Args>
    void RunVoid(const std::string & name, Args... args) {
        if (this->lockedEnv != nullptr){
            this->lockedEnv->CallVoidMethod(this->instanceRef, this->callbacks[name], args...);
            return;
        }

        JNIEnv *env = this->LockEnv();
        env->CallVoidMethod(this->instanceRef, this->callbacks[name], args...);
        this->UnLockEnv();
    };
};
```

I have tried to simplify code as much as possible, but with JNI its hard.

Comment: Though I didn't get this specific error when interacting with the JNI, believe it or not I found a (boolean) variable I needed to mark as `volatile` because it was being stripped by the optimizer. It was a variable set by the calling thread to `true` and then set to `false` within the thread. I was able to track it down because it was very specific behavior which was controlled by that boolean which was stripped. Not sure if that helps, but might be something to look into.

Comment: What does `Result` look like? Also check `javaCallback` is not null.. Also what happens if you call `GetMethodID` inside the `CppGetData` thread instead?
Note, you do NOT need to guard the `env` with a mutex as it can't ever be used from a different thread.

Comment: Is `SimpleJNIClass` used from multiple threads? If so it'll return the `env` from one thread on another thread which will cause issues

Comment: That error indicates that the `jmethodID` is `null`. Can you confirm that `javaCallback` is non-null when this crashes?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure what's the purpose of calling it via the `lockedEnv*`? Why not use the passed in `env`?

Comment: I have found out that in Release mode, this call `jobject inst = this->lockedEnv->NewObject(this->callbackClass, this->callbacks["<init>"], args...);` returns `nullptr`. However, I am not sure why.

Comment: Make sure that none of the Java classes and methods that you reference from native code are obfuscated by R8 or ProGuard.

Comment: JNI troubleshooting basics: Always call `ExceptionOccurred` after every JNI call, and enable [extended checking](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended-checking).

Comment: @MartinPerry Do you have any class/method in Java that is ***only*** constructed/called from the native side? In that case, the class could possibly be removed by Progaurd and you would end with a null `jobject/jmethod` on release builds. You could use the `-keep` Proguard rules/ [`@Keep`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep) etc. to avoid this.

Comment: The used class is constructed only in JNI and read in Java, but class is anotated with ´@Keep’

Comment: Is `getData` ever called from a native thread (ie not one created from Java)? In that case [`FindClass` will return `null`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class) and so will attempts to look up methods in said `null` class.

Comment: ´getData´ Is called from java

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Exactly this problem. Method not found in release mode.